# Is there a way to detect with Google-Apps-Script whether Google Sheets is opened from Android app or from desktop browser?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a small script that I have further reduced for the sake of this question. Basically it implements the `onEdit` function in which it may show an alert (using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()`) and will always show a message box (`using Browser.msgBox()`).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const rg = e.range;

  // Do some stuff on rg and show alert if some condition is met.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Alert text!');

  var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Confirm','Are you sure?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (confirm != 'ok') {
    return;
  }
  
  // Do some stuff.
}
```

The problem is the alert and message box are not working from Android app which compromises the whole function execution and the wanted changes do not happen. So I would like to detect if the sheet is opened from the Android app and if so skip showing the alert and message box but if a desktop browser is used, I still would like to show them.

I have browsed through the Script Services menu at [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base) but I did not find anything that could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script services doesn't include a way to detect the if the user is using the desktop UI or the mobile app.

Possible workarounds

- Instead of using Class UI methods like `alert` or `prompt` or Class Browser methods, set a range as a notification area and put there your messages.
- Instead of using Google Sheets for data entry use a Google Form or create an app using Google Apps Script or [AppSheet](https://www.appsheet.com/).

Related

- [How to detect mobile user with Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58229683/1595451)
- [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33373826/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to detect whether I am running using a browser on my Windows PC or on my Android mobile. I declare ui as a file level variable and then attempt to access it:

```
ui=null;

function getUserIf(){
  if(ui == null){
    try{
      ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    }catch(err){
      Logger.log(">>"+ui);
    }
  }
}
```

After calling `getUserIf()` you can test whether `ui` is still `null` to decide where you are running the script.